# Ideals question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I=\left\{ f[X]\in\mathbb{C}[X]\mid f(0)=f(1)=f(-1)=0\right\}$. $\;I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X]$.

(i) Show that $f[X]$∈$I$ if and only if $X(X-1)(X+1)|f(X)$.

(ii) Deduce that $I=(X^3-X)$ is the principal ideal generated by $X^3-X$.

I am stuck on (i). I know that it is an iff statement so I did so I considered if $f[X]$ is in I, and I let $X=0$, $1$, $-1$ and found that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)=0$ so $X$, $X+1$ and $X-1$ are all factors of $f(X)$. But what next.

Comment: Do you know (and can prove) that if two coprime natural numbers divide a third one also the greater common divisor of the first two divides the third one? Well, almost the same here...

Comment: huh i have no idea what that is

Comment: Hmmm...$$a,b,c\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\begin{cases}a\mid c\;,\;\;b\mid c\\{}\\gcd(a,b)=1\end{cases}\implies ab\mid c\ldots?$$

Comment: do we just say without proof that the highest common factor for X and X-1 is 1?

Comment: @snowman: since $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a Euclidean domain, you can algorithmically compute $\gcd(X, X-1) = 1$ without too much difficulty. Alternatively, you can just note that $X - (X-1) = 1$ (and similarly, $(X+1)-X = 1$, etc.).

Comment: Saying stuff without proof in mathematics can be highly risky: either one already proved this or else you can prove it *now*.

Comment: @snowman have you discussed varieties at all?

Comment: what is varieties?

Comment: Why would they, @Gage? And why would they need to? This is abstract algebra, not algebraic geometry.

Comment: @Timbuc I missed the tag and just read the question my bad. I was only asking because this is a really natural (and easy) question if you use varieties to talk about it.

Comment: @snowman they are the set of zeros of polynomials (and relate to ideals of a polynomial ring) but they aren't typically discussed in a first course in abstract algebra

Comment: I really cant do this question.... if a|f and b|f and c|f then you can rewrite them as f=Xa=Yb=Zc where X,Y,Z belong to I right?

Comment: snowman I think you are on the right track with $f = g\cdot a$ and then since you know that $b$ divides $f$ you have that $b \vert g \cdot a$ then if $b$ doesn't divide $a$ (you should prove this in your case) you can write $f = g \cdot a = g' \cdot a \cdot b$.

Comment: Also "$f=Xa=Yb=Zc$ where $X,Y,Z$ belong to $I$ right?" isn't quite right because $X,Y,Z$ don't have to be in $I$ (this is because $I$ isn't prime) for example $f=x^3 - x$ is in your ideal and $x$ divides it so we have $f=x \cdot(x^2 - 1)$ and $x^2 - 1) isn't in your ideal

Comment: what exactly is in my ideal? the complex number notation scares me. what is C[X]? is it the same as C={a+bi:a,b are real}?

Comment: @snowman $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is the ring of all polynomials with coefficients in the complex numbers. What is in your ideal is any polynomial that is zero for $x = -1, 0 , 1$. For example $x^3 - x$ is zero for all there of those values of $x$ and so it is in $I$ while $x^2 -1$ is not zero for $x = -1$ and therefore isn't in $I$.

Comment: What part of your question wants you to show is that anything in $I$ can be written as a product of $X^3 - X$ and some element of $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: can you write C[X] as a set please. because that's the thing that is confusing me the most.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[x] = \{f = \sum c_i x^i \}$ where $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and the sum is finite. You can read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#The_polynomial_ring_K.5BX.5D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is more than one question in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **(i)** $f(X)\in I \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad (X-1) X (X+1) \mid f(X)$

**"$\Longrightarrow$"** As you mention, given $f(X)\in I$, since $f(1)=f(0)=f(-1)=0$, $X-1,\ X,\ X+1$ are factors of $f(X)$, and therefore
$$f(X) = h(X) \cdot (X-1) X (X+1)$$
and we are done.

**"$\Longleftarrow$"** This part is easy, if $(X-1) X (X+1) \mid f(X)$, then $f(X) = h(X) \cdot (X-1) X (X+1)$, so $f(-1)=f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(X)\in I$.

### **(ii)** $I=\langle X^3-X\rangle$

Well, since $X^3-X = (X-1)X(X+1)$, you just need to know the definition of $\langle X^3-X\rangle$:
$$f(X)\in I \quad \overset{(i)}{\Longleftrightarrow} \quad X^3-X\mid f(X) \quad \overset{def}{\Longleftrightarrow} \quad f(X) \in \langle X^3-X\rangle$$

---

*If the steps given in (i), "$\Longrightarrow$" were not trivial to you, here is a more detailed proof.*

Since $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is an Euclidean Domain, you can use Euclidean Division. Given $f(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X]$, write:
$$
f(X) = q(X)\cdot(X-1) + r,\quad \text{where}\quad
q(X)\in\mathbb{C}[X],\  r\in \mathbb{C}.
$$
In particular, if we let $X=1$, we find $f(1) = r$.

Now, given $f(X)\in I$, we have $f(1)=0=r$ and therefore:
$$
f(X) = q(X) \cdot (X-1)
$$
Furthermore, $f(0) = 0$ implies $q(0)=0$, and we can apply the same idea to $q(X)$ and $X$ to show:
$$
q(X) = p(X) \cdot X
$$
Finally $f(-1)=0\Rightarrow q(-1)=0 \Rightarrow p(-1)=0$ and again:
$$
p(X) = h(X) \cdot (X+1)
$$

Then we have $f(X) = h(X) \cdot (X-1) X (X+1)$, and we have shown:
$$f(X)\in I \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (X-1) X (X+1) \mid f(X)$$

Comment: what exactly is a 'principal ideal'? and you said 'you just need to know the definition of ...', what is the definition? how come you use these brackets <> instead of ()? Sorry I am confused. please help.

Comment: @snowman An ideal $I$ is principal when it is generated by a single element $a\in R$. In this case we write $I=\langle a \rangle$ (or $I=(a)$, the two notatios are used). By definition, $b\in \langle a \rangle \Leftrightarrow b = ar$ for some $r\in R$, this is the same as $b\in \langle a \rangle \Leftrightarrow a \mid b$. Anyway, take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal).